# glext visual studio cuda

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, cuda

I am currently in a parallel computing class using a book called Cuda by Example.  In Chapter 4 of this book I am using some .h files that contain includes for "GL/glut.h" and "GL/glext.h", I have steps for installing GLUT online, and followed those.  I think that this worked but I am not sure.  I then tried to find directions for glext, but I cannot seem to find as much on this.  I did find one .h file and tried to use that by including it in the GL folder as well.  This does not seem to work because I received errors when compiling of things similar to this:

> Error 1   error : calling a host function("cuComplex::cuComplex") from a **device**/_*global*_ function("julia") is not allowed   C:\Users\Laptop\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Lab1\Lab1\lab1.cu 29  1   Lab1

I think this is because I need more for glext.h, like .dll and things similar to the glut, but I am not sure.  Any help with this would be appreciated.  Thank You.

**EDIT:**- this is the code that I am using, and I have not changed it from what I see in the book, except for the top two include statements and the .h files are from [google code](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-examples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/common%253Fstate%253Dclosed): thank you for any help

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "book.h"
#include "cpu_bitmap.h"

#define DIM 1000

struct cuComplex {
    float r;
    float i;
    cuComplex( float a, float b) : r(a), i(b) {}
    __device__ float magnitude2(void) {
        return r*r + i*i;
    }
    __device__ cuComplex operator* (const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r*a.r - i*a.i, i*a.r + r*a.i);
    }
    __device__ cuComplex operator+ (const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r+a.r, i+a.i);
    }
};

__device__ int julia( int x, int y) {
    const float scale = 1.5;
    float jx = scale * (float)(DIM/2 -x)/(DIM/2);
    float jy = scale * (float)(DIM/2 - y)/(DIM/2);

    cuComplex c(-0.8, .156);
    cuComplex a(jx, jy);

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<200;i++) {
        a = a * a + c;
        if(a.magnitude2() > 1000)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

__global__ void kernel(unsigned char *ptr ) {
    //map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
    int x = blockIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y;
    int offset = x + y * gridDim.x;
    //now claculate the value at that position
    int juliaValue = julia(x,y);
    ptr[offset*4 + 0] = 255 * juliaValue;
    ptr[offset*4 + 1] = 0;
    ptr[offset*4 + 2] = 0;
    ptr[offset*4 + 3] = 255;
}

int main( void ) {
    CPUBitmap bitmap(DIM, DIM);
    unsigned char *dev_bitmap;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_bitmap, bitmap.image_size()));
    dim3    grid(DIM,DIM);
    kernel<<<grid,1>>>( dev_bitmap );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( bitmap.get_ptr(), dev_bitmap, bitmap.image_size(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    bitmap.display_and_exit();
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( dev_bitmap ));
}
```

Comment: I don't think the error is connected to your inclusion or not of GL/glut etc.  It's probably best if you post the code you're using (you can edit your question to do this).  Have you modified it from what is presented in the book?

Comment: Thank you, I added the code to the comment as you suggested, and I don't think I modified it from the book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the following.

Original code:

```
cuComplex( float a, float b) : r(a), i(b) {}
```

Modified:

```
__host__ __device__ cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a), i(b)  {}
```

It fixed the issue for me.  I also didn't need the two include files you added, but you may depending on your build process.

A CUDA program consists of 2 types of code: host code and device code.  Host code runs on the host CPU and cannot run on the GPU, and device code runs on the GPU and cannot run on the CPU.  If you don't decorate your program in any way, then it will be all host code.  But once you start adding CUDA sections delineated by keywords like __ global__ or __ device__ then your program will contain some device code.

The compiler error you received indicated that a function that was running on the device was attempting to use code compiled for the CPU.  This is a no-no and the compiler will not allow this.  This example is unusual since at some point in time (when the book was written) it presumably did not generate this error, and furthermore the code in cuComplex struct appears to be decorated with __ device__ keyword.  However at the outermost level of the struct at the line of code I modified, there is no keyword identifying __ device__ .  When I add the  __ device__ __ host__ keywords, this tells the compiler "for this logical section, create both a device-compiled version and a host-compiled version of the code".  This explicitly tells the compiler you want to be able to use this section of code in the device.  And with that addition, we have steered the compiler correctly and it no longer gives the complaint.

Apparently something has changed about the level of decoration that the compiler needs to generate device code in this case.  Presumably, with older compilers, the __ device__ keywords inside the struct were enough to let the compiler know that it had to generate device versions of the operators callable by cuComplex type.

Comment: Thank you this did allow it to compile, but when I tried to run it my display driver stops working do you have any suggestions for this? Also would you be willing to explain what this changed? Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer with explanation about the code change.  Regarding the display driver issue, are you able to run any other CUDA codes?  Is it only this code where you see this problem or does it happen with any CUDA code?

Comment: I am able to run the CUDA sdk samples, and the examples earlier in the book with vector summing and basic addition.  This is the only other code I have attempted to run and I the driver stops responding.  The driver is 306.23, according to the error message if that matters.  Again Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: the code is supposed to display a fractal image.  Do you see that at all?  On my laptop the code takes about 1 second to run before the fractal image is displayed, however it may be slower on other GPUs.  If the code takes more than about 1-2 seconds to run on a windows laptop, you may hit a [windows TDR.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx) To test this theory, try changing the #define DIM 1000 to #define DIM 200 and see if you can run the program successfully.  This will show the "same" image but in a smaller window. If that works, then it's probably a TDR

Comment: Thank you so much! When I change the DIM to 200 I do successfully see the image in a smaller window.  Do you have any suggestions for increasing this timeout, or should I just use a smaller window size?

Comment: I don't know what your needs are.  If running in a smaller window is OK, that is certainly simplest.  You can make the DIM larger to see how big it can get before the TDR kicks in.  To change the TDR requires changing registry values on your machine.  I don't know how comfortable you would be with that.  If it's something you want to do, I would suggest googling "disable TDR windows 7" and review some of the top hits, as well as the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx) I previously indicated.  I don't have an exact set of instructions to give you.